Why does taking derivatives work here for finding the sum of squares?
So I have been recently trying to figure out how to derive sums of powers, and have recently rederived$$S=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$although admittedly I'm not exactly sure why the method I used to derive this sum works.
Here's my method of deriving this sum:

First, set 2 boundary conditions for this formula, those being$$S(1)=1\\S(2)=5$$These will be important later.
Then, I noticed that I could think of a (definite) sum as an operator that in this case transforms a function, say $f(i)$, into an explicit formula in terms of $n$, say $\hat f(n)$. Because of this (although I probably would need to prove rigorously the mathematical validity of this to justify this step), I then took$$\dfrac d{di}\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac d{di}i^2=2\sum_{i=1}^ni$$which then I can sum up to get$$2\sum_{i=1}^ni=n(n+1)$$
Taking the indefinite integral of this result, I then get$$\int n(n+1)dn=\int (n^2+n)dn\\=\dfrac{n^3}3+\dfrac{n^2}2+\color{red}{g(n)}=\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+g(n)}6$$and now we are ready to plug in our boundary conditions.
Plugging in our boundary conditions, we get$$S(1)=1=\dfrac{5+g(1)}6\implies g(1)=1\\S(2)=5=\dfrac{28+g(2)}6=\dfrac{14}3+\dfrac{g(2)}6\implies g(2)=2$$and from here, either by mathematical induction or by considering more test cases, we find that$$g(n)=n$$and therefore$$\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}6=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$

While overall I am able to overall understand the reasoning behind the steps that I took, I'm not really sure I can say the same about my second step.
Question:

Why is the second step I took mathematically valid?


You might want to look into "discrete calculus."  I don't have a whole lot of practice with it myself, but it creates operators that are equivalent to the derivative and the integral with step sizes that are "large."  There is a set of transformations for the standard functions in regular calculus to equivalent functions in discrete calculus.  And the transformations are invertible, so you can solve discrete problems with regular calculus.

You can look at the summation operation as a form of calculus...  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_derivatives_and_integrals_in_alternative_calculi   for a list of this and other types of calculus

Formally differentiating and then proving the result works afterward is precisely what one does when proving Faulhaber's Formula, which generalizes your result. You have basically rediscovered this without proof. This process is known as Umbral Calculus.

One may convert any integer into an integral: $\int_0^11di=1$, $\int_0^21di=2$,...,$\int_{0}^k1di=k$, and any square into a double integral $2\int_0^1idi=1$, $2\int_0^2idi=4$,...,$2\int_{0}^kidi=k^2$. The rest follows by linearity of the differential and integral operators, and the fundamental theorem of calculus applied with the upper limits of the intervals of integration, $k$, as real variables, which gives the $dn$ integral in step 3. I have surely left some notational mixup, even errors, as i didn't write down details, but kudos to you, i think that is a clever idea, which works.

You essentially want the method of differences. For the sum of squares, we have $f(1) = 1^2 = 1, D_1(1) = f(2) - f(1) = 4, D_2(1) = D_1(2) - D_1(1) = 9-4 = 5, D_3(1) = D_2(2) - D_1(1) = 7 - 5 =  2$, so $ f(n) = 1 + 4(n-1) + 5/2(n-1)(n-2) + 2/6(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$.

@plm I don't understand your logic. So we have $ \sum_i  i^2 = \sum_i 2 \int_0^i  j dj $. How do we continue from there? Note that the limits of the integration are different, so we can't just "linearity of operators" out of it. How do yo continue from the RHS? I could make $ = \int_0^k \lfloor n+1-j \rfloor j , dj$, but that's not an obvious integral with the discrete floor function.

@CalvinLin Right now the best explanation i get is that we take a variable $t\in[0,1]$ and functions $i_1(t)=2t$, $i_2(t)=4t$,... $i_n(t)=2nt$, which we all integrate from $0$ to $1$ and sum from $1$ to $n$. Then we integrate again $\int_0^1\frac{n(n+1)}{2}dx=\sum_{j=1}^n\int_0^1i_jdx=\sum_{j=1}^n\int_0^1\int_0^1jdx^2$ so that $x$ is $n$ but rescaled in each integer-integral to get the right integer, and the 1st equality i cannot explain yet, but may involve linearity when proving $1+2+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. It's not baked yet but now i don't have the time to think through it, sorry.

For what is worth: $\frac{d}{d k} , \sum_{k=0}^{n} f_{k}$ is an invalid statement. The index of summation is not a function of the result of the summation. The statement $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{d f_{k}}{d k}$ is a valid statement because the variable $k$ is within the summation (using variable $k$ and $f_{k}$).

@CalvinLin Third try. Start with the vector space of rational polynomials on variables $x_i$, $i\in\mathbb N$. Quotient by $x_i+x_j=x_{i+j}$, $x_i^k=x_{i^k}$. Define $Dx_{n^2}=Dx_n^2=2x_n$, $Dx_{n^k}=Dx_n^k=kx_{n^{k-1}}$, extend by linearity. Define $S=D^{-1}$ on the same vector space, at $0$ define $S0=0$ - or we have to adjust with initial conditions. Then we have $D\sum x_i^2=2\sum x_i=2x_{n(n+1)/2}$, $S2x_{n(n+1)/2}=S(x_nx_{n+1})=Sx_n^2+Sx_n=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}$. Perhaps i am less wrong this time, surely i will need another try. I still think there is something to understand here.

@CalvinLin Try #4.1. Let $f(X,Y,Z,x,y,z)$ be differentiable with $\partial_Xf=\partial_Yf=\partial_Zf$, then $\partial_X\int\int\int fdxdydz=\partial_Y\int\int\int f=\partial_Z\int\int\int f$ by the Leibniz rule - the integrals are over $\mathbb R^3$. Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus $\int\int\int f(X,Y,n,x,y,z)=\int_{Z=0}^n\partial_Z\int\int\int f(X,Y,Z,x,y,z)dZ=\int_{Z=0}^n\partial_X\int\int\int fdZ$. Apply this to an appropriate function on $\mathbb R^6$, i think that $f(X,Y,Z,x,y,z)=\mathbb 1_{[0,X+Y+Z]\times[0,X+Y+Z]\times\mathbb R^4}(x,y,z)\sum_{i=1}^Z\delta_0(x+y+z-i)$ works.

Try #4.2. Then we can interchange the derivative wrt $Z$ -ie $n$- and that wrt $X$ -ie $i$- as done by the OP. "Morally" the contruction in my third try was meant to be an algebraic realization of this trick. Anyway, sorry that this new attempt fails again, but i abandon here. I still think it is possible to formalize and generalize the OP's heuristic - and im not sure it has to do with the umbral calculus that a comment mentions.

Honestly, I don't think that step is valid or invalid. I'll explain what I mean:
The result of the third step is the formula
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{2n^3+3n^2 + g(n)}6.
$$
This formula is tautologically valid for some function $g(n)$. (Indeed one way of writing that function is $6 \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 - 2n^3 - 3n^2$.) So the steps before it weren't needed to prove its validity.
The problem still remains to identify the function $g(n)$. The OP offers two explanations:

by “considering more test cases”—this isn't a valid proof, since no finite amount of data will prove the formula $g(n)=n$ in general;
by “induction”—this is certainly valid—but the original problem could be tackled by induction to begin with, and the calculation is essentially exactly the same.

So the idea of “taking the derivative of a sum with respect to the upper index” isn't a mathematical step at all, but rather a heuristic step that produces a formula with an unknown function, and hopefully it's easier to conjecture a formula for that unknown function from data.
Side note: the discrete analogue of the derivative is the difference operator, and it is possible to solve problems like this using properties of the difference operator that are somewhat analogous to properties of differentiation.
